# how to change gc_maxlifetime in zend framework run time

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have used setExpirationSeconds to session out, but not all session out..

```
$objSessionNamespace = new \Zend\Session\Container( 'Zend_Auth' );
           $objSessionNamespace->setExpirationSeconds(60);
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove a session by key you can use `offsetUnset`, this will justunset a session variable by session key, As below:

```
$objSessionNamespace = new \Zend\Session\Container( 'Zend_Auth' );
$objSessionNamespace->setExpirationSeconds(60);
$objSessionNamespace->offsetUnset('key');
```

Again, if you want to distroy the whole session data of a particular namespace,

```
$objSessionNamespace = new \Zend\Session\Container( 'Zend_Auth' );  
 $objSessionNamespace->getManager()->destroy();
```